# eclipse plugin, Palette, can not show icon

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

the icon can not be shown properly in Palette, just a red dot. when I run the example to develop my own options for Palette: 
the code below:

```
ImageDescriptor descriptor =   
                    ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(   
                        PracticeEditor.class,   
                        "icons/arrow.gif");

PaletteDrawer drawer = new PaletteDrawer("Example");
        ToolEntry tool = new SelectionToolEntry();

        List entries = new ArrayList();
        //
        tool = new CombinedTemplateCreationEntry("Node", "Create a new Node", Node.class, new SimpleFactory(
                Node.class), descriptor, descriptor);
        entries.add(tool);
```

they did not show the icon properly, just a red dot. Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Resolve it, because of the address should be abs path, and put null as the class loaction.